# Are there any JavaScript properties related to web browser form validation in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, html

In HTML5, the client side validation should become a job of the web browser, via attributes like `pattern` or `required`.

Is there only a CSS implementation of this (i.e. the `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors, to give feedback to the user) or is there also a JavaScript implementation?

I’m thinking of something like a feature allowing a JavaScript function to get called if the user clicks submit and the form has invalid values in it. Or a flag that I can access in the form object to show if it has errors or not.

Thanks.

Comment: subjective and argumentative. I think you want programmer.stackexchange.com

Comment: @apphacker: really? Looks to me like the question is asking if it’s possible to access results of the browser’s validation via JavaScript. That’s not argumentative, that’s asking if a capability exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a `validity` attribute you can query. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-validity

I've no idea how much support for this exists in browsers currently.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does, and it currently works.  See [A List Apart's](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/forward-thinking-form-validation/) excellent article on the subject by Ryan Seddon.  According to the article, Chrome 4+, Safari 5+ and Opera 9.6+ all support the properties.  (He also includes [an example](http://www.alistapart.com/d/forward-thinking-form-validation/index.html).)

Quoting from the article, you can do things like:

```
input:focus:required:invalid {
  background: pink url(ico_validation.png) 379px 3px no-repeat;
}
input:required:valid {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: 379px -61px;
}
```

And when an input validates it will display one icon, and when it is invalidated and focused it will display another.